# How to find which partition is skewed (while joining large tables)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am joining 2 large tables (billions x hundreds of millions of rows) by an id.  e.g.,

```
table1.join(table2, Seq("id"))
```

My Spark Jobs gets to this point "fairly quickly":

```
Stage 19: 60000/60001 (1 running)
```

**The problem is that this 1 running job takes hours which is an order of magnitude more than the other jobs.**

==> How can I determine which "key" in the join is causing the long running job?

==> Is there a way to write to stdout of the executor to give more debug information?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are joining based on the column Id

One easy thing which I follow is to count max occurrence of an Id.

```
df.groupBy("id").count.sort(desc("count")).take(10).foreach(println)
```

This will give you top 10 "id" which has max number of occurrences in the dataset.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I can get the counts on both sides of the table, but I believe it's combined count that matters (i.e., there might be an id that's really big on one side of the table, but have no corresponding id on the other)?   Also, is there a way looking at the executor what it's actually doing?  I could be totally wrong about this being the problem.

Comment: Even if there is less count on the other side still spark will send all the same ID to the same box so data skew in any side will probably is an issue. To look which executor doing the job , you can look at the spark UI. In the executor page it shows which executors are running. In case of data skew generally only 1 executor will be running. So you will be able to figure out from there